# How to find the correct mask given one?

Tags: c, microcontroller, texas-instruments

For a TM4C microcontroller, to enable the clock for port F, I would do something like this:

```
*pRCGCGPIO = *pRCGCGPIO | 0x20;
```

This uses the mask `0x20`.

To enable the clock for port C, what would the correct mask be?

Comment: Read the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tm4c123gh6pm.pdf) for your microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Since 0x20 matches F, I assume the masking looks like this:

```
00100000 // 0x20 in binary
HGFEDCBA
```

Which means you'd need `0x04 (=00000100)` for port C.